# How to destruct lists in nushell

Tags: nushell

I have `hello` command exported from the module `greet`. I have also defined the `main` command which use the `hello` command. The [rest parameters](https://www.nushell.sh/book/custom_commands.html#rest-parameters) should be passed to `hello` from `main`.

I'm expecting `hello` command `$values` to be following when `./file.nu one two` is ran,

```
╭───┬─────────╮
│ 0 │ one      │
│ 1 │ two      │
╰───┴─────────╯
```

But the actual value is

```
╭───┬────────────────╮
│ 0  │ [list 2 items] │
╰───┴────────────────╯
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env nu

module greet {
  export def hello [...values: string] {
    echo $values

    $values | each { $"Hello ($in)" }
  }
}

def main [...names: string] {
  use greet hello;

  echo (hello $names) | length
}
```

How to destruct `$names` before passed into `hello` command?

Comment: it seems list spreading is not implemented yet. https://github.com/nushell/nushell/issues/3276#issuecomment-1126571911

Comment: Side-note:  Consider dropping the `echo`.  E.g. simply `(hello $names) | length`.  I keep forgetting to do that in PowerShell, myself.

Answer (score 1):

As long as there isn't yet (as [@don_aman](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/534154/don-aman) mentioned in the comments) a list spreader operator in Nu, it may be good practice to design functions with rest parameters to be able to handle either:

- Individual arguments (the normal "rest" case)
- A single list being passed in (the non-destructured case)

*Option 1:*  Attempt to auto-detect the situation.  It's possible that there are corner cases here, but maybe not.

For example, the following `greet` properly handles either:

- `[one two three]` (the rest parameters to `main`), which are then destructured inside `greet`
- `four five six`, which are simply passed as rest parameters to `greet`

```
#!/usr/bin/env nu

module greet {
  export def hello [...values: string] {
    let values = if (($values | length) == 1) and (($values.0 | describe | str substring ',5') == "list<") {
        $values.0
      } else {
        $values
      }

    $values | each { $"Hello ($in)" }
  }
}

def main [...names: string] {
  use greet hello;

  hello $names
  (hello $names) | length

  hello four five six
}
```

```
> ./greet.nu one two three
╭───┬─────────────╮
│ 0 │ Hello one   │
│ 1 │ Hello two   │
│ 2 │ Hello three │
╰───┴─────────────╯
3
╭───┬────────────╮
│ 0 │ Hello four │
│ 1 │ Hello five │
│ 2 │ Hello six  │
╰───┴────────────╯
```

---

*Option 2:* As an alternative, you could explicitly tell `greet` when to destructure and when not to via a flag:

```
#!/usr/bin/env nu

module greet {
  export def hello [
    --destruct
    ...values: string
  ] {

    let values = if $destruct {
        $values.0
      } else {
        $values
      }

    $values | each { $"Hello ($in)" }
  }
}

def main [...names: string] {
  use greet hello;

  hello $names
  (hello $names) | length
  hello --destruct $names
  (hello --destruct $names) | length

  hello four five six
}
```

```
./greet.nu one two three
╭───┬─────────────────────────╮
│ 0 │ Hello [one, two, three] │
╰───┴─────────────────────────╯
1
╭───┬─────────────╮
│ 0 │ Hello one   │
│ 1 │ Hello two   │
│ 2 │ Hello three │
╰───┴─────────────╯
3
╭───┬────────────╮
│ 0 │ Hello four │
│ 1 │ Hello five │
│ 2 │ Hello six  │
╰───┴────────────╯
```